# WPF semi cascading listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have 3 controls on my page

- ListBox A
- ListBox B
- ComboBox C

ListBox A is databound to a collection of items A

ComboBox C is databound to a collection of items C

ListBox B is databound to a collection of items B

B has a reference to Item A and Item C, the ListBox B should only show the items where Item A is the selected item of ListBox A, and Item C is the selected item of ListBox C

i've messed a little with collectionviews as ItemSource on ListBox B, setting a filter, but I can only get it to update the content of ListBox B based on either ListBox A or ComboBox C, not them both at the same time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view model, give the `CollectionView` a filter predicate, something like this:

```
Items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_Items) as CollectionView;
Items.Filter = (x => ((Item)x).CategoryA == SelectedCategoryA 
                && ((Item)x).CategoryC == SelectedCategoryC);
```

Bind the list/combo boxes' `SelectedItem` to `SelectedCategoryA` and `SelectedCategoryC` properties.  In the setters for those properties, call `Items.Refresh()`.

**Edit**

In your list box, bind both `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem`, e.g.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryListA}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategoryA, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In your view model, create a property like this:

```
private Category _SelectedCategoryA;

public Category SelectedCategoryA
{
   get { return _SelectedCategoryA; }
   set
   {
      if (value != _SelectedCategoryA)
      {
         _SelectedCategoryA = value;
         Items.Refresh();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to bind the selecteditem and calling items.refresh?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a seperate collection of Item B from a public accessor property collection of type b. like this.

```
private List<B> m_trueCollection; //the actual collection of B
public ObservableCollection<B> FilteredB { get; set; } //bind to this
```

Then, listen in to whenever there is a change to the selected item of ComboBox C or Listbox A. using the `SelectionChanged` Event property.

If a selection is changed, iterate the true collection and rebuild FilteredB according to your criteria.

Hope it helps.